# Is there a way to work with files in python without downloading the files

Tags: python, azure, pdf, png

I am writing code in python in order to download pdf-files and png-files, and then extracting information from the files. However, I have to make it compatible with Microsoft-Azure, which does not allow me to save the files before i read them. Is there a simple way to keep the files in memory while I read them, without having to save the files?

Comment: You are using azure blob?

Comment: As of right now I am not using azure blob, but if that might solve the problem I might start using it. The best solution would be one without azure blob though

Comment: What version of Python SDK you're using?

Comment: That I do not know. I am completely new to Azure, so how would I figure that out?

Comment: You must have installed some package via pip for managing Azure Storage. That would be the SDK you are using.

Comment: Also, please edit your question and include the code that you have written so far.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution by using tempfiles such as this. I worked with pollen btw.

```
with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as fp:
    for chunk in pollenfile.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        # writing one chunk at a time to pdf file, because pdf is so large
        if chunk:
            fp.write(chunk)

    pdfReader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(
        fp
    )  # Discerning the number of pages will allow us to parse through all the pages.
    num_pages = pdfReader.numPages
    count = 0
    pollen_txt = ""  # The while loop will read each page.
    while count < num_pages:
        pageObj = pdfReader.getPage(count)
        count += 1
        pollen_txt += (
            pageObj.extractText()
        )
```

By doing this I extract the pdf in a string format, without ever saving it to my computer, which I can later manipulate.